# Solving third order linear ODE using symmetric square basis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In M. van Hoeij talk on "Solving Third Order Linear Differential Equations
in Terms of Second Order Equations" (2007) he mentions the following algorithm.

"Case 1 (the easiest case): Is $L$ the symmetric square of a second order operator?

Let $L = \partial^3 + c_2(x) \partial^2 + c_1(x) \partial + c_0(x) $. $L$ is a symmetric square if there exist functions $y_1, y_2$ such that $y_1^2, y_1y_2, y_2^2$ is a basis for its solutions. In this case,
$y_1, y_2$ are solutions of some operator $L_2 = \partial^2 + a_1(x) \partial + a_0(x)$. Testing if $L$ is symmetric square and finding $L_2$ is easy: take $a_1 = c_2/3, a_0 = (c_1 - a_1' -2a_1^2)/4$, and test if $4a_0 a_1 + 2a'_0 = c_0$."

I tried looking up over the internet to find more references about this topic but unfortunately could not find anything.

My basic questions are:

1. How is result on how to find $L_2$ derived?
2. How is test for $L$ being symmetric square derived?

More advanced questions are:

1. What is the intuition behind this method? How can one come up with it?
2. Is there a generalization to $n$-th order ODEs?